# Magento 2 - javascript translations not working

Tags: javascript, localisation, magento2.4.5

I got a shop with 4 different languages en/de/fr/it. Now I installed translation modules which have their files under app/i18n additionally I have a custom theme under with language files under app/design/frontend/mine/custom/i18n

all that seems to work fine if I use php. All translations are present. If I use js, the translations are not present. I checked the js-translation.json it regenerates during static file generation  but does not include the translation strings. But it is also not empty. A fraction of translations is added. If I manually add my string for testing then it's being translated in js. So it's just not added for some reason.

Does someone know why or have a hint how I can track that issue down?

thx

Answer (score 1):

Are you writing JS translation in a `.js` file or in a `.phtml` ?

To generate the `js-translation.json` file, Magento will scan all `.js` and `.html` project files, but not `.phtml` or `.php` ones.

When Magento detect a string (in `.js` or `.html`), it looks inside the CSV translations files and if it match, Magento put the translation inside the `js-translation.json` file.

This can be why you don't find your strings in your `js-translation.json`.

TLDR:

When you write javascript code in a `.phtml` file, you should use the php function `__()` to translate your content.